# Explicitly accept change for PPA 'Label'

Tags: apt, ppa

When I run `apt-get update` on my ubuntu 17.10 I receive the following error:

```
E: Repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful InRelease' changed its 'Label' value from '*****
The main PPA for PHP (5.6, 7.0, 7.1) with many PECL extensions *****' to '*****
The main PPA for supported PHP versions with many PECL extensions *****'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied.
See apt-secure(8) manpage for details."
```

The man page doesn't really point to a solution.  My question is, how do I explicitly accept the change?

Comment: FWIW, apt-get is somewhat depreciated, use apt . `sudo apt update` etc.

Answer (score 319):

It would help if you posted your repositories, but, with that said, you sort of have 2 ways to fix this.

First would be to use `apt` rather than `apt-get`. `apt` is preferred over `apt-get` for interactive use in recent Ubuntu versions; and `apt` should, in theory, fix this for you.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Your second option is to use `--allow-releaseinfo-change`

```
sudo apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change
```

If those options do not resolve the issue, please post your repositories, are you using mixed repositories or pinning, and, finally, tell us, is this an upgrade ?

Comment: I get an error when using the second command:
# sudo apt-get --allow-release-info-change update
E: Command line option --allow-release-info-change is not understood in combination with the other options

Comment: Using `sudo apt update` fixed the issue. I was prompted: "Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N]".

Comment: the `apt-get` command worked for me, with the `--allow-releaseinfo-change` _after_ the update command.

Comment: None of those options work if you invoke `apt` non-interactively (e.g. the shell does not have a controlling terminal). Even the `--yes` option is ignored without a controlling terminal.  Only if you run those commands from a gnome-terminal (or xterm, or whatever terminal) do those options work.

Comment: it works great !

Answer (score 81):

You need to use `apt` instead of `apt-get`. It will ask you to accept the changes interactively. Simply run:

```
sudo apt update
```

It should ask you:

```
Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N]
```

Answer (score 13):

If you want to deploy it e.g.  run in on many servers at once then execute:

```
apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change
apt-get update
apt-get install packagename
```

Comment: No need for the second `apt-get update`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, anyhow, the answer was here:

https://neon.kde.org/faq#command-to-update

And I give you the link because I assume it's updated as needed.  Currently, it reads that you must run:

```
pkcon refresh
pkcon update
```

Which is what I'm running.  Hopefully, my computer will still work once it's done.