# E: Repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'bionic-updates' to 'bionic-security'

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager, repository

I am running Ubuntu 18.04. I wanted to install `node` and `npm` on my machine. The apt repository version of node is 8.x, whereas I wanted to have version 12.x (Current LTS version).

I followed the guide here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18-04

As per the guide, I downloaded
`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x -o nodesource_setup.sh`

and then ran it with
`sudo -E ./nodesource_setup.sh`

---

However, my machine fails to run `sudo apt update` with the following (full) output:

```
maxim@fujitsu:~/scripts$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                 
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease         
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease              
E: Repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'bionic-updates' to 'bionic-security'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N] N
Fetched 88.7 kB in 8s (10.5 kB/s)                                                      
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054624/repository-security-problems?noredirect=1) suggests that one should use `apt update` instead of `apt-get update`. None the less, I am running `apt update`.

[This answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/989906/explicitly-accept-change-for-ppa-label) suggests to answer "Y" to the prompt.

[This github issue](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/812), from the Docker community, makes it clear that doing so is a bad idea.

However, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/528751/cannot-update-apt-list-repository-no-longer-has-a-release-file), suggests that sometimes repositories change the names of package sources.

So my question is, is it OK to answer Y here? I don't want to  just blindly accept whatever error the package manager throws at me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't answer `Y` to the question you never will get apt-get (or apt) working.

It seems reasonable that a security repository sets its 'Suite' value to 'bionic-security'. Why it was `bionic-updates` I can't tell, but it probably was an error.

As for `apt-get` contra `apt`, apt was introduced in Ubuntu 16.04 as a new interface to the package system - se here: https://itsfoss.com/apt-vs-apt-get-difference/

Answer (score 3):

To fix the "**changed its 'Suite' value**" issue run the following commands:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```